# How does the triggers fires in sql?

Tags: sql, triggers

If I have a trigger like the following one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T
AFTER UPDATE ON SERVER
FOR EACH ROW

WHEN condition

BEGIN
INSERT INTO tab1 ... VALUES (...)
UPDATE SERVER SET freememory = freememory + 2
DELETE tab2 WHERE ID = 2
END;
```

How does the triggers are fired? I mean, once the second query (UPDATE SERVER ...) is executed I should re-call the execution of the same trigger.
It isn't clear to me if before re-executing the trigger I execute the DELETE tab2 (and so I wait the end of my actual trigger), or if the trigger is re-executed right after the update query and so all the delete are postponed.
I am considering a general SQL language, not related to a specific vendor.

Thank you

Comment: There's no general solution here, different products do things in different ways.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks!

Comment: However, I'd expect a trigger to be executed "at once". I.e. if your trigger code performs an INSERT, and the table has an insert trigger, that trigger should be executed before the first trigger continues.

Comment: Triggers are highly vendor specific (I am not even sure they are part of the SQL standard). So this can't really be answered in a general way.

Answer (score 0):

The triggers are activated when asked: some before and some after. If we create a trigger that activates after an update then the trigger will activate itself

Comment: Ok, this is clear, but I wanted to know "how much after", I mean after also the delete or before it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it depends on what you put: after delete then it will be after or before delete it will be after the delete. The trigger allows you to choose if it is before or after